# SQL Server date range query not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I wrote a query for return orders received for a certain date range. The goal is to find orders made in a few hours for online and store. However, the order return ORDER_IDs that are outside the date range. Here is my query.

```
SELECT 
    ORDER_ID 
FROM 
    ORDERS 
WHERE 
    TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'ONLINE' OR TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'STORE' 
    AND ORDER_COUNT > 0 
    AND (ORDER_DATE >= '2017-11-20 02:04:25.247' 
         AND ORDER_DATE< '2017-11-20 02:06:40.887')
```

Now when I run a query with one of the `ORDER_ID` returned, it returns a date range outside the lower date value.

```
  SELECT ORDER_DATE FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_ID=104 

  ORDER_DATE
  -----------
  2017-11-24 10:10:14.520
```

This clearly is incorrect.  Why is it returning a date greater than  2017-11-20 when the date range is supposed to be between 2017-11-20 02:04:25.247 and 2017-11-20 02:06:40.887?

How can I fix the query to find orders a few hours apart, for example orders made on the same day between 3pm and 8pm?

When I tried the suggestion I get no rows, even though there are rows in the date range.

```
ORDER_ID    ORDER_DATE              TRANSACTION_TYPE
433         2017-11-20 02:04:25.247         ONLINE
448         2017-11-20 02:06:40.887         ONLINE
```

Comment: You've mixed AND and OR's together, these should be in parenthesis to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
     WHERE(    
         TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'ONLINE'
         OR          
         TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'STORE' 
   )    

   AND  ORDER_COUNT > 0 

   AND 
   (     

     ORDER_DATE <CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 

     AND

     ORDER_DATE > DATEADD(hh,-3,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)  
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

your `WHERE` condition is wrong. Maybe should be like this

```
WHERE  (    -- added this
             TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'ONLINE' 
        OR   TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'STORE' 
       )    -- added this
AND    ORDER_COUNT > 0 
AND    (     
             ORDER_DATE >= '2017-11-20 02:04:25.247' 
        AND  ORDER_DATE <  '2017-11-20 02:06:40.887'    
       )
```

you missed out some parenthesis ( ) somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed AND's and OR's together. One solution is to use IN for TRANSACTION_TYPE instead of two statements with OR operator.  This avoids mixing of AND and OR.

```
SELECT ORDER_ID 
  FROM ORDERS 
 WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE IN ('ONLINE', 'STORE')
   AND ORDER_COUNT>0 
   AND ORDER_DATE >= '2017-11-20 02:04:25.247' 
   AND ORDER_DATE< '2017-11-20 02:06:40.887'
```

Another possibility is to use parenthesis to group the OR statements.